# Background image doesn't load on mobile for all browsers except Firefox

Tags: css

I'm assuming this problem may have something to do with the size. It's a 9MB image.
It loads on every browser on PC but only Firefox on mobile.

Here it is:

Code blocks are being a pain in the arse so I'm displaying in plain text

```
html {
    background:url(/images/signup-background.jpg) 
no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-ms-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
font-family:'Share Tech Mono', sans-serif;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: It displayed as a code block anyways. How cool

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's displayed as a code block because the text is indented four spaces.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a code block by preceding and following the code with a line consisting of triple backticks ```.